# Show that $x_1x_2\cdots x_n (mod~ m)\equiv (x_1 (mod~m)\cdot x_2 (mod~m)\cdots x_n (mod~m))(mod~ m)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Show that $x_1x_2\cdots x_n (mod~ m)\equiv (x_1 (mod~m)\cdot x_2 (mod~m)\cdots x_n (mod~m))(mod~ m)$

I know that $a\equiv b (mod ~ m)$, $c\equiv d (mod ~m)$ implies $ac\equiv bd (mod ~m)$ but how to go with the problem here.

Comment: The result that you know is essentially the case $n=2$; use that to prove the general result by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write $x_j=q_jm+r_j,j\in{\Bbb{N}}$. We have

$$x_j\equiv r_j\pmod{m}$$

For $j=1 \text{ to } n$, we have $n$ similar relationship. What can you conclude?